# How to enable cookie support with pyWebKit?

Tags: python, cookies, webkit

The documentation for pyWebKitGTK is pretty scarce. I've looked through their python `.def` files but they don't seem to contain the words cookie, session, (lib)soup or (lib)curl.. so maybe it isn't possible, huh. I've also looked through the WebKitGTK docs (for the C-based library) and aside from a brief mention of libsoup there doesn't appear to be anything there either. But on the other hand cookie support seems like pretty fundamental stuff. Could anyone confirm / deny PyWebKitGTK's support of cookies?

Note: am currently using the GTK version, but I don't mind switching to the Qt one if the feature is there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**webkit** is a html renderer, not a complete browser. I guess you must deal with persisting the cookies yourself.

Comment: Hmm yes I guess I was confused about that at first. However, I still can't see how to add cookie capability to it.. I looked at the WebKitGTK browser [surf][1] and it calls `webkit_get_default_session()` to get the cookie data (or something like that). But there is no analog of that function in the Python version. I'm guessing that it might simply have not been implemented?
[1]: surf.suckless.org

Comment: I've got to disagree, the library OP mentions come with a default cookie jar that works, it just doesn't persist cookies between sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that WebKitGTK supports cookies, and that you can use them with pywebkitgtk and ctypes successfully- though I'm not sure if that was the case when this question was posted!

To make cookies persist in a useful way, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722590/218160).