# python webkit webview remember cookies?

Tags: python, cookies, webkit

I have written a short python script that opens Google music in web view window. however I can't seem to find anything about getting webkit to use cookies so that I don't have to login every time I start it up.

Here's what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gtk, webkit
import ctypes

libgobject = ctypes.CDLL('/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0')
libwebkit = ctypes.CDLL('/usr/lib/libsoup-2.4.so.1')
libsoup = ctypes.CDLL('/usr/lib/libsoup-2.4.so.1')
libwebkit = ctypes.CDLL('/usr/lib/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0')

proxy_uri = libsoup.soup_uri_new('http://tcdproxy.tcd.ie:8080') #proxy urli

session = libwebkit.webkit_get_default_session()
libgobject.g_object_set(session, "proxy-uri", proxy_uri, None)

w = gtk.Window()
w.connect("destroy",w.destroy)
w.set_size_request(1000,600)
w.connect('delete-event', lambda w, event: gtk.main_quit())
s = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
v = webkit.WebView()
s.add(v)
w.add(s)
w.show_all()

v.open('http://music.google.com')
gtk.main()
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated,
thanks,

Richard

Comment: Working on this, myself. For clarity for others who might be able to answer this, consider fixing all the ctypes lines- pretty sure the first `libwebkit` reference was an accident.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Worked it out, but it required learning more ctypes than I wanted -_-. Try this- I required different library paths, etc than you, so I'll just paste what's relevant.

```
#remove all cookiejars
generic_cookiejar_type = libgobject.g_type_from_name('SoupCookieJar')
libsoup.soup_session_remove_feature_by_type(session, generic_cookiejar_type)

#and replace with a new persistent jar
cookiejar = libsoup.soup_cookie_jar_text_new('/path/to/your/cookies.txt',False)
libsoup.soup_session_add_feature(session, cookiejar)
```

The code's pretty self explanatory. There's also a [SoupCookieJarSqlite](http://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/stable/SoupCookieJarSqlite.html) that you might prefer, though I'm sure the text file would  be easier for development.

EDIT: actually, the cookie jar removal doesn't seem to be doing anything, so the appropriate snippet is

```
#add a new persistent cookie jar
cookiejar = libsoup.soup_cookie_jar_text_new('/path/to/your/cookies.txt',False)
libsoup.soup_session_add_feature(session, cookiejar)
```

Comment: worked flawlesly for me, this also fixed an issue I had with webkit + iframe + a payment provider we are using..

Comment: worked less flawlessly when i tried adding it to a gtk thread

Answer (score 6):

I know its old question and have been looking for the answer all over the place. Finally came up on my own after some trial and error. Hope this helps others.

This is basically same answer from Matt, just using GIR introspection and feels more pythonish.

```
from gi.repository import Soup
cookiejar = Soup.CookieJarText.new("<Your cookie path>", False)
cookiejar.set_accept_policy(Soup.CookieJarAcceptPolicy.ALWAYS)
session = WebKit.get_default_session()
session.add_feature(cookiejar)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version i.e. `GTK WebKit2 4.0`, this has to be done in the following way:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Soup', '2.4')
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')

from gi.repository import Soup
from gi.repository import WebKit2

browser = WebKit2.WebView()

website_data_manager = browser.get_website_data_manager()
cookie_manager = website_data_manager.get_cookie_manager()
cookie_manager.set_persistent_storage('PATH_TO_YOUR/cookie.txt', WebKit2.CookiePersistentStorage.TEXT)
cookie_manager.set_accept_policy(Soup.CookieJarAcceptPolicy.ALWAYS)
```