# webkit: is it possible to store cookies to file and reuse it again?

Tags: python, webkit, gtk

is it possible to store cookies to file when you use webkit and reuse it again next time when I run my application?

Comment: @arxanas I could not find in docs how to do that, I found http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/unstable/WebKitCookieManager.html but nothing more

Comment: @arxanas there is nothing about how to link my webkit.WebView() with this WebKitCookieManager

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python webkit webview remember cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766445/python-webkit-webview-remember-cookies)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know its old question and have been looking for the answer all over the place. Finally came up on my own after some trial and error. Hope this helps others.

```
from gi.repository import Soup
cookiejar = Soup.CookieJarText.new("<Your cookie path>", False)
cookiejar.set_accept_policy(Soup.CookieJarAcceptPolicy.ALWAYS)
session = WebKit.get_default_session()
session.add_feature(cookiejar)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using WebKit and Gtk, change the first line from:

```
from gi.repository import Soup
```

to:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit, Soup
```

to avoid static and dynamic conflicts.