# How to specify the user data dir or profile dir (for cookies) in embedded Webkit?

Tags: python, webkit, pygtk

I have a small python gtk application with embedded webkit. Much like this [example code](http://www.eurion.net/python-snippets/snippet/Webkit%20Browser.html).

The problem is, that my logins (cookies) are not persisted in my application.

I think I need to specify a custom directory, where webkit will save its data (especially cookies). So how to set the directory on my embedded Webkit?

Some time ago I was using gtkmozembed. There I just had to call `gtkmozembed.set_profile_path(my_custom_dir, "profile")`. Is there something similar for webkit?

Comment: Have you tried the `Webkit2.WebsiteDataManager` that is set in the `Webkit2.WebContext`? (See the [docs](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#WebKit2-4.0/classes/WebsiteDataManager.html#properties))

Comment: I think this already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220373/webkit-is-it-possible-to-store-cookies-to-file-and-reuse-it-again/15800193#15800193)

Comment: @elya5 "'WebContext' object has no attribute 'get_website_data_manager'". Ubuntu comes with "gir1.2-webkit2-3.0" while version 2.10 seams to be required for this API :-(