# python webkit : hack and custom

Tags: python, webkit, webkitgtk, python-webbrowser

I have done a python webkit navigator, with GTK.
And, as I better know html/css for rendering than others ways, I have done a software using python, wekbit and GTK.

I got some questions. I have read documentation that I found, and did a lot of researchs on google and stackoverflow. I still got lot of questions.

First, in my app, I change the title of the window to communicate between javascript and python. I wish to do the same in my navigator, but I can not (I need title). Is their any others ways ?
I would love to bind javascript events listeners to python, without changing the title.

***EDIT***

I have found a solution. We can bind some events to python.
You can have more documentation about events in python :

```
import webkit
help(webkit.WebView)
```

I have tried with console-message. This events returns me 4 args : webview, webframe, int, msg. What is the int ? In most of messages it is valued to 13... If someone know what it means.

Second, my linux version of my navigator plays really well media element (audio, video...). I assume, it is because linux rulz and depedencies are pretty well installed on my computer.
But on windows it is another things ...
I have seen that I can build webkit for windows with these dependencies.
But I have found some javascript codecs for reading media elements (https://github.com/audiocogs). Should it be better than I inject this javascript, or compiling webkit in my own way ?

Third, can I handle cache settings ? I am pretty sure that now, there is no cache in my browser. (my code is really light now on).

Fourth, can I handle HTTP request ? (cookies, apache auth, ...)

Fifth, I use WebView.zoom_in(), and zoom_out functions. And definitively it has not the same behaviour than firefox or chrome when I zoom_in or zoom_out.
With firefox or chrome, it's like if zoom_out make you have more pixels than before. I mean if you zoom out on chrome, you can have different media queries than before.
With WebView zooms functions, it's like if there is only the font size who change.
How could I do zooms like firefox and chrome ?

Sixth, I could use gecko engine instead of webkit. But I do not know, how to choose between those twos.
It seems that webkit is nicely imported in python and gtk, and linux. But gecko probably too. How could I, in a cleverway, choose ?

Seventh, I got some streaming problems. For instance, if I want to hear some long music, or some videos, and pause them for some times, when I play back the media, my browser bug. There is no error in console, and the webkit.webview is all blank. I can reload, and it works again... How can I handle this error ?

Some relevant samples of my light code :

```
class nav:

 def __init__(self):
  self.browser = webkit.WebView()
  self.browser.connect("create-web-view",self.set)
  self.browser.set_full_content_zoom(True)
  self.browser.get_settings().set_property("enable-webaudio",True)
  self.browser.open(url)

 def on_zoom_in(self, widget):
  self.browser.zoom_in()

 def on_zoom_out(self, widget):
  self.browser.zoom_out()

 def on_zoom_n(self, widget):
  self.browser.set_zoom_level(1.0)
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Not the answers for all the questions you have, but this will help.

There is no need to change the title for communicating between javascript and python. You can alert mechanism. Some examples can be found https://github.com/nhrdl/notesMD - the tool I wrote few days back. In simplest terms, your script uses alert function and python gets the callback. You can parse the text of alert message and decide on action.

Your code has nothing to do with webkit cache. Its function of what pages your application is visiting and what server prefers. Server can ask for some resources to be cached (e.g. images/javascript) and others not to be cached. I know webkit gtk 2 supports some more functions for caching, but don't recall much in Webkit gtk 1. I have seen it caching the files in your home directory though.

For cookies look at [python webkit webview remember cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766445/python-webkit-webview-remember-cookies/15800220#15800220). Webkit also has various methods to get request and response and you can listen to various soup events for the things that interest you.

I have not read about python bindings for geco engine. That does not mean it does not exists, only I have not seen it.

Comment: How can I know if I use webkit gtk 1 or 2 ?
Should I use v2 ?

Comment: I will use your code tonight and this week end.
I come back to you if I got any trouve but than you dude!

Comment: I have done some trials. Ok so javascript can speak with python with alerts. But alerts are displayed...
Can I force to not display alerts ?
Where can I found all events that I can connect from javascript to webview ? (like script-alert, or title-changed ...)

Comment: Last time I checked, webkit 2 bindings were not out. So chances are high that you are actually using webkit 1. As for hiding alerts, I think you will have to return true to indicate that default handlers should not be executed. Available objects and details are at http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html