# Python webkitGtk Cookie

Tags: python, webkitgtk

I made a small webkitgtk browser embedded in a gkt3 app. 
All is workng fine except i cant save cookies.i found here [7766445](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766445/python-webkit-webview-remember-cookies/8722590#8722590):

```
cookiejar = Soup.CookieJarText.new("cookie.txt", False)
cookiejar.set_accept_policy(Soup.CookieJarAcceptPolicy.ALWAYS)
session = WebKit.get_default_session()
session.add_feature(cookiejar)
```

it create the cookie file with this text inside:

```
> # HTTP Cookie File
> # http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
> # This is a generated file!  Do not edit.
> # To delete cookies, use the Cookie Manager.
```

but nothing happened when i send a cookie from the site after login.
i am searching a working example or some advise to add cookies with introspection.

Thanks
EDIT:

i have to correct that the cookie is in some way managed until gtk app restart but this happened also without the cookiejar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python webkit webview remember cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766445/python-webkit-webview-remember-cookies)